# How to transforming values from the list using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have dictionary and list:

```
dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}

data = [2, 0, 5, 1, 0]
```

Then I would like to transform the data from the list in the following way.
If `data[i]%3 == 0` then `data[i] ='a'`,
if `data[i]%3 == 1` then `data[i] ='b'`,
if `data[i]%3 == 2` then `data[i] ='c'`.

what should it give:

```
data2 = ['cacba']
```

With a small number of conditions, there is no problem, but how can this be automated and linked to a dictionary, for example with 100 values in a dictionary?

Comment: Your dict looks related to 'abc', and you can grab the letter you want from 'abc'[data[i]%3]. So a simple solution to the above immediate sample problem would be ['abc'[i % 3] for i in data]. I just thought it interesting. It doesn't help your generic problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
new_dict = {b:a for a, b in dict.items()}
data = [2, 0, 5, 1, 0]
final_data = [''.join([new_dict[a%3] for a in data])]
```

Output:

```
['cacba']
```

Comment: I would\did rename OP's dict too. xD

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach you might take to solving the problem presented in your question:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import operator


def main():
    dict = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
    data = [2, 0, 5, 1, 0]

    table = ''.join(map(
        operator.itemgetter(0),
        sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    ))
    size = len(dict)
    data2 = [''.join(table[i % size] for i in data)]

    print(f'data2 = {data2}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The size of your initial `dict` and `data` variables should not matter if they have certain constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Create method like this;

```
 def get_letter(number){
    if number%3 == 0:
      data[i] ='a'
    if number%3 == 1:
      data[i] ='b'
    if number%3 == 2:
      data[i] ='c'
}
```

And call in main function;

```
   data = [2, 0, 5, 1, 0]
    data2 = []

    for i in range (len(data)):
       data2.append(get_letter(data[i])); 

    print data2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use a dict like this:
`dict = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}`

Then, you need only to map a simple function to your list:

`result = [''.join(map(lambda x: dict[x % 3], data))]`

If you still need to use that dict, you could reverse it

```
rev_dict = {val: key for key, val in dict.items()}
result = [''.join(map(lambda x: rev_dict[x % 3], data))]
```

**Edit**: the result you asked for was a list

Comment: All in all, I'm not strictly bound with the order of the dictionary. I can use it :)

Comment: Then this structure is better, the other way could fail if you have the same value for distinct keys in your initial dict